# Training LIBSVM with multivariate data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

How LIBSVM works performs multivariate regression is my generalized question? 
In detail, I have some data for certain number of links. (Example 3 links). Each link has 3 dependent variables which when used in a model gives output Y.  I have data collected on these links in some interval.

```
LinkId | var1 |  var2  | var3 | var4(OUTPUT)
   1   |  10  |  12.1  |  2.2 |  3
   2   |  11  |  11.2  |  2.3 |  3.1
   3   |  12  |  12.4  |  4.1 |  1
   1   |  13  |  11.8  |  2.2 |  4
   2   |  14  |  12.7  |  2.3 |  2
   3   |  15  |  10.7  |  4.1 |  6
   1   |  16  |  8.6   |  2.2 |  6.6
   2   |  17  |  14.2  |  2.3 |  4
   3   |  18  |  9.8   |  4.1 |  5
```

I need to perform prediction to find the output of

```
(2,19,10.2,2.3).
```

How can I do that using above data for training in Matlab using LIBSVM? Can I train the whole data as input to the svmtrain to create a model or do I need to train each link separate and use the model create for prediction? Does it make any difference?
NOTE : Notice each link with same ID has same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a `matlab` or `libsvm` question but rather a generic `svm` related one.

> How LIBSVM works performs multivariate regression is my generalized question?

LibSVM is just a library, which in particular - implements the Support Vector Regression model for the regression tasks. In short words, in a linear case, SVR tries to find a hyperplane for which your data points are placed in some margin around it (which is quite a dual approach to the classical SVM which tries to separate data with as big margin as possible).

[image: source:kernelsvm.tripod.com/]

In non linear case the kernel trick is used (in the same fashion as in SVM), so it is still looking for a hyperplane, but in a feature space induced by the particular kernel, which results in the non linear regression in the input space.

[image]

Quite nice introduction to SVRs' can be found here:
http://alex.smola.org/papers/2003/SmoSch03b.pdf

> How can I do that using above data for training in Matlab using LIBSVM? Can I train the whole data as input to the svmtrain to create a model or do I need to train each link separate and use the model create for prediction? Does it make any difference? NOTE : Notice each link with same ID has same value.

You could train `SVR` (as it is a regression problem) with the whole data, but:

- seems that `var3` and `LinkId` are the same variables (`1->2.2, 2->2.3, 3->4.1`), if this is a case you should remove the `LinkId` column,
- are values of `var1` unique ascending integers? If so, these are also probably a useless featues (as they do not seem to carry any information, they seem to be your `id` numbers),
- you should preprocess your data before applying SVM so eg. each column contains values from the `[0,1]` interval, otherwise some features may become more important than others just because of their scale.

Now, if you would like to create a separate model for each link, and follow above clues, you end up with `1` input variable (`var2`) and `1` output variable `var4`, so I would not recommend such a step. In general it seems that you have very limited featues set, it would be valuable to gather more **informative** features.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding with clear response. Let me be more clear with the data I have. The data I have is a car data which travels on different links for different time intervals. So the var1 is time of the day which is continuous, var2 is speed of the car at different times, var3 is the link length. var4 is the time taken on that link which is the required output. So, now can you give me your suggestions. I added var3 because the link lengths are not equal. I would be glad if you could help in predicting time taken for  future  travel with input link Id, Speed and time of travel